# PCL - can I target .NET 4.5 and ".NET 4.0 with BCL extensions"

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

I have a Portable Class Library project which currently targets the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8

I'd like to add support for .NET 4.0, but I currently use some .NET features, which are *only* available in .NET 4.0 through inclusion of the "[Microsoft BCL Portability Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)"; features like the [CallerMemberName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, the [IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, and the updated Task class.

Is there a way to add some 'conditional' support for a platform, in a PCL project?  I.e. "allow .NET 4.0, as long as dependency XXXXX is included?"

Comment: No, *very* different reference assemblies.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you completely. But, if you let your PCL unconditionally target .NET 4.0 and reference the *BCL Portability Pack*, I think you should be able to safely consume the PCL library also in a .NET 4.5 application, because the BCL portability pack will forward the use of types already existing on the specific target to the actual implementation on this target.

Comment: Considering the fact that .NET 4 will be dead in about 15 months (end of life on Jan 12, 2016), http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework I feel that any attempt to extend support to it a waste. When Microsoft released BCL Portability Pack they obviously only focus on a few initiatives, which do not cover PCL. So focus on what you can control and suggest your clients to upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 ASAP, as there is only 15 months ahead.

Comment: As someone working in the industrial space, where many many customers are still using Windows XP (for some reason), I'd have to disagree.  Even though support for Windows XP has been cut off by Microsoft, I still have to write software that will run on it.  .NET 4.5 applications do not run on XP. Yet, I still pine for some of the features that were added after 4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, target .NET 4 in the PCL and reference the Microsoft.Bcl and probably Microsoft.Bcl.Async packages.

You can consider packaging up your PCL as a NuGet package with those packages listed as a dependency.  That way when your NuGet package is installed in a project the required Microsoft.Bcl packages will also be installed.